# Healthchecks for SOAP service in asp.net microservice

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, soap, health-check

I have this setup for a HealthCheck for a WCF SOAP service and for some reason the code in the second delegate is not executed. If I put breakpoint it's not hit also in debug.

```
HealthCheckConfiguration healthCheckConfiguration = new ();
configureHealthChecks.Invoke(healthCheckConfiguration);
 
services
    .AddHealthChecks()
    .AddUrlGroup(
        (uriOptions) => uriOptions.UseHttpMethod(HttpMethod.Head),
        healthCheckConfiguration.Name,
        healthCheckConfiguration.FailureStatus,
        healthCheckConfiguration.Tags,
        healthCheckConfiguration.Timeout,
        (serviceProvider, httpClient) =>
        {
            var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<TSettings>>();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new($"{config.CurrentValue.Endpoint}?wsdl");
        });
```

The similar delegate in the second sample is hit and is working correctly, but we want to change the request for the HealthCheck from GET to HEAD.

```
services
.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddUrlGroup(
        (services) =>
        {
            var config = services.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<TSettings>>();

            return new Uri($"{config.CurrentValue.Endpoint}?wsdl");
        },
        healthCheckConfiguration.Name,
        healthCheckConfiguration.FailureStatus,
        healthCheckConfiguration.Tags,
        healthCheckConfiguration.Timeout);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, I have changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try a custom check:

```
public class ServiceCheck : IHealthCheck
{
    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        bool result = IsServiceOnline();
        if (result)
            return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
        return HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy();
    }

    private bool IsServiceOnline()
    {
       //Your custom needs, such as HttpMethod.Head and other things
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<ServiceCheck>($"{config.CurrentValue.Endpoint}?wsdl");
}
```